# Duda configuración WCF en IIS con SSL

Tags: c#, iis, wcf, ssl, certificado-ssl

Necesito crear un servicio WCF alojado en IIS y que para que sus contratos (métodos públicos) puedan ser accedidos se tenga que suministrar un usuario y una contraseña (que no tienen que ser usuarios de windows).
También es deseable que como el servicio va a ser visible desde internet, utilice SSL.
Llevo todo el día probando ejemplos y tutoriales y no he conseguido que me funcione.

Agradecería alguna guía o mejor aún, un ejemplo que funcione.
No sé qué incluir en esta pregunta de todas las pruebas y cosas que he hecho, así que responderé cualquier pregunta que me hagáis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola toda la seguridad del servicio se controla desde el webConfig y en el caso del endpoint por defecto que te genera el wcf es basicHttpBinding si no lo hiciste tu, depende de como queres exponerlo debes cambiar el endpoint, en tu caso deberias usar wsHttpBinding y luego le activas la seguridad ya que por defecto viene desactivad. Wcf tambien te permite como seguridad usar el usuario de windows, certificados, o login personalizado, seguridad en el transporte de la información. Cuando elijas debes configurar el endpoint y en binding

```
<system.serviceModel>  
<bindings>  
  <wsHttpBinding>  
    <binding name="myBinding">  
      <security mode="Message"/>  
      <message clientCredentialType="Windows"/>  
    </binding>  
</bindings>  
</system.serviceModel>
```

te dejo el link de referencia de microsoft.
https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/programming-wcf-security